# Match string with 1 or more trailing substrings

Tags: php, regex

I have an input that goes like this

```
[d/D/d1/d2/d3/d4/d5/d6/d7/D1/D2/D3/D4/D5/D6/D7]+[\.]+[r1/r2/r3/r4/r5/r6/R1/R2/R3/R4/R5/R6]+[\.]+[number 1 to 37]+[#]+[number 0 - 9 ]
```

An example would be "d2.r1.4#100.37#1.9#2.3#1(can have as many 1-37 # 0-9 as needed)"

How do I write a regex match that can allow the last part of the string to be dynamic (matches as many groups as needed as inputted)

I've tried this expression:

```
[dD1-7]+\.[rR1-5]+\.
```

and I'm not sure how to match the dynamic group that comes after the "d2.r1." part.

Comment: Few test cases (valid/invalid) would be helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you merely need to validate the string (and not capture/extract specific substrings), the following pattern provides the same result as Emma's answer but with a tighter syntax.

The `i` pattern modifier means you only have to write the two letters in lowercase.  I don't use any excess non-capturing groups.  Two-character character classes don't need a hyphen.  `\d` is the shorter way of expressing `[0-9]`.

Wrapping the final/repeating characters in parentheses then writing `*` means the sequence in the parentheses may repeat zero or more times.

Code: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/kQtAU))

```
$inputs = [
    'd2.r1.4#100.37#1.9#2.3#1',
    'd2.r1.4#100.37#1.9#2.38#1.8#22',
    'd2.r1.4#100.37#1.9#2.3#1.12#2.30#2',
];

$pattern = '/^d[1-7]\.r[1-6](?:\.(?:3[0-7]|[12]\d|[1-9])#\d+)*$/i';

foreach ($inputs as $input) {
    echo "\n{$input}: ";
    var_export((bool)preg_match($pattern, $input));
}
```

Output:

```
d2.r1.4#100.37#1.9#2.3#1: true
d2.r1.4#100.37#1.9#2.38#1.8#22: false
d2.r1.4#100.37#1.9#2.3#1.12#2.30#2: true
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing that maybe some expression similar to,

```
^[dD][1-7]\.[rR][1-6](?:(?:\.(?:3[0-7]|[1-2]\d|[1-9]))#[0-9]+)*$
```

or with some slight changes, would likely work here.

#### Test

```
$re = '/^[dD][1-7]\.[rR][1-6](?:(?:\.(?:3[0-7]|[1-2]\d|[1-9]))#[0-9]+)*$/m';
$str = 'd2.r1.4#100.37#1.9#2.3#1
d2.r1.4#100.37#1.9#2.3#1.37#1.9#2.3#1.37#1.9#2.3#1.37#1.9#2.3#1
d2.r1.4#100.38#1.9#2.3#1
d2.r1.4#100.0#1.9#2.3#1
';

preg_match_all($re, $str, $matches, PREG_SET_ORDER, 0);

var_dump($matches);
```

#### Output

```
array(2) {
  [0]=>
  array(1) {
    [0]=>
    string(24) "d2.r1.4#100.37#1.9#2.3#1"
  }
  [1]=>
  array(1) {
    [0]=>
    string(63) "d2.r1.4#100.37#1.9#2.3#1.37#1.9#2.3#1.37#1.9#2.3#1.37#1.9#2.3#1"
  }
}
```

---

If you wish to simplify/modify/explore the expression, it's been explained on the top right panel of [regex101.com](https://regex101.com/r/vjYzYR/1/). If you'd like, you can also watch in [this link](https://regex101.com/r/vjYzYR/1/debugger), how it would match against some sample inputs.

---

#### RegEx Circuit

[jex.im](https://jex.im/regulex/#!flags=&re=%5E(a%7Cb)*%3F%24) visualizes regular expressions:

[image]